# Insert comma only after first comma and if it is number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following string coming from the API. and due to some reasons **POSTALCODE** comes in the middle and I want to separate it with a comma.

`1234 17/3 Street, 23455 Mike Road, Denvor`

I need to put comma just after `23455` so the out put will be,

`1234 17/3 Street, 23455, Mike Road, Denvor`

Since this pattern is always same from the API. looking for regex solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Additionally, when you say "this pattern is always same" what exactly do you mean by that? Please provide multiple examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Something like this might possibly capture what you want: `const addComma = str => str.replace(/(\d+)([^,]+),([^,]+)$/, '$1,$2,$3')`.  But without more information, it's impossible to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for `(^[^,]*,[^,]*\d+)` and substitute with `$1,`: https://regex101.com/r/pIcUjx/2

Explanation: 
we start with a start of the line and look for the first comma: `^[^,]*,`
after that we look for the nearest number (no commas between the first comma and the number): `[^,]*\d+`

If found match, then put a comma after the number.

Comment: Very good explanation about how it works. Thank you.